# OSError: socket no longer exists (Python IDLE error)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, python-3.5

First let me give some background information that lead to the problem.
I had/have two versions of python installed in my Win 8.1 laptop. Originally Py 2.5 was set as the default. The way i did it was that i renamed the `python.exe`  of Python 3.5 as `python35.exe` and the file 
`pythonw.exe` 
as `pythonw35.exe` which seem to have created two `.dll` files with the same names to that of the two files (I don't remember whether the two dll files were present before the renaming) and successfully set Python 2.7 as default (i.e. when i typed the command `python` in the command line, python 2.7 ran). Recently i needed to set Python 3.5 as default. I then proceeded to rename the files of the version `Python 2.7` the same way and reverted the file names of the 3.5 version to their original normal formats (i.e. `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`).

After all this mayhem, i run `print("Hello World")` in the IDLE and it springs up the following error:

```
IDLE internal error in runcode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 339, in putmessage
    r, w, x = select.select([], [self.sock], [])
TypeError: argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 240, in asyncqueue
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "C:\Python35-32\lib\idlelib\rpc.py", line 342, in putmessage
    raise OSError("socket no longer exists")
OSError: socket no longer exists
```

Comment: The DLLs were not created by renaming the executable. Python 3.5 no longer installs python35.dll in the System32 directory when installing for all users. It's always beside python.exe. Per-machine installations also default to "Program Files [(x86)]" now, the preferred and secure directory for programs.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same problem.This error raised due to naming my file as "collections". That means if you are naming your files as any inbuilt function, keyword, module etc. this error will raise.

Solution for this error is, check whether you have created any file by any  inbuilt function, keyword, module etc. If yes then rename the file name which is not related to any python keyword. It will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

So i just installed the python 3.5.1 setup again and things are up and running.

Comment: if anyone has any idea about why the error occurred in the first place is welcome to post an answer.

Comment: Don't rename the executables because .py and .pyw files are (and should be) associated with the [py.exe and pyw.exe launchers](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), which use the registry to find installed interpreters and run python.exe or pythonw.exe. You can create *copies* with names like "python2.7.exe" and "python3.5.exe" if you like, and manage `PATH` to pick which "python.exe" is preferred. Or just use `py.exe` and set `PY_PYTHON=2` or `PY_PYTHON=3` to select the default. Run `py -X[.Y[-32]]` to override the default.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions do not work, a simple restart may solve the problem. You can restart Python shell or your device. If the problem still persist, I recommend reinstalling python.